# MySql using OR in an IF THEN END IF inside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

How is `OR` used in `IF THEN ELSE END IF` inside a MySql stored procedure?

```
DECLARE userKey BOOL;

SET userKey = True;

IF makeKey != 'open' or makeKey != 'mask' THEN
 SET userKey = False;
END IF;

IF (makeKey != 'open') or (makeKey != 'mask') THEN
 SET userKey = False;
END IF;

IF (makeKey != 'open') || (makeKey != 'mask') THEN
 SET userKey = False;
END IF;

Note: Not all the above are used together.
```

Neither of the above three work. They dont throw an error, but simply evaluate to false.

The stored procedure is call like usual `myProc('open')`; I'm going wrong with the `OR`. How do I get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you want `AND`, not `OR`:

```
IF makeKey != 'open' AND makeKey != 'mask' THEN
   SET userKey = False;
END IF;
```

The `OR` will always be true.  If `makekey = 'open'`, for instance, then it certainly is not also equal to `'mask'`.

This is more easily written as:

```
IF makeKey NOT IN ('open', 'mask') THEN
    SET userKey = False;
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. And thanks for the second version too. Makes things lots easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your "Or"s to "and"s

Currently your query will always give UserKey = false as MakeKey will always not be one of those values.